# Is there a combination of LaTeX gnuplot flowchart?

Tags: diagrams, gnuplot

I know this is not always a good idea, but I think it might be a good idea in some situation.

Is there an improved LaTeX version or something, can have the `gnuplot` scripts inside of the LaTeX file, so during compilation, it can compile the `gnuplot` scripts as well. Now we have to generate the EPS file first, or `.tex` file first.

The same apply to flowchart, I really wish there could be a solution that can dynamically compile and build in the flowchart scripts in the LaTeX file.

Am I missing something or what?

Comment: There is the [`gnuplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gnuplot) package. Also, [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) can work with gnuplot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's the package `gnuplottex` that does exactly what you want. Here's an example document, say `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb,ifthen,moreverb,gnuplottex}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf]
      set   autoscale                        # scale axes automatically
      unset log                              # remove any log-scaling
      unset label                            # remove any previous labels
      set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
      set ytic auto                          # set ytics automatically
      set title "Force Deflection Data for a Beam and a Column"
      set xlabel "Deflection (meters)"
      set ylabel "Force (kN)"
      set key 0.01,100
      set label "Yield Point" at 0.003,260
      set arrow from 0.0028,250 to 0.003,280
      set xr [0.0:0.022]
      set yr [0:325]
      plot    "force.dat" using 1:2 title 'Column' with linespoints ,                 "force.dat" using 1:3 title 'Beam' with points
\end{gnuplot}

\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=pdf]
plot sin(x)
\end{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

along with the standard `force.dat` file

```
# This file is called   force.dat
# Force-Deflection data for a beam and a bar
# Deflection    Col-Force       Beam-Force 
0.000              0              0    
0.001            104             51
0.002            202            101
0.003            298            148
0.0031           290            149
0.004            289            201
0.0041           291            209
0.005            310            250
0.010            311            260
0.020            280            240
```

If compiled with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test
```

the result will be

[image]

You can use the `gnuplot` environment just like any other LaTeX environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can either do it via the `\write18` command

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
 \immediate\write18{dir > test}
\end{document}
```

You just have to exchange the `dir > test` against the gnuplot call you need. The `\immediate` prefix will ensure that the command is executed immediately. The content of the write18 command will be expanded and executed on the shell.

For `\write18` to work you have to enable it (is is disable for security reasons, so that an arbitrary package can't e.g. format you harddrive). Enabling `\write18` is done with the `--enable-write18` command line switch. E.g.

```
pdflatex --enable-write18 myfile.tex
```

I can't provide a exact gnuplot example, since I'm on windows and don't have gnuplot installed, but you should get the idea.

Comment: The option is `--shell-escape` on Unix systems and TeX Live on Windows, and it should work also with MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: I'm running texlive on windows & linux, and `--enable-write18` & `--shell-escape` both seem to work both.

Comment: Apparently both distributions accept both options. Good news.