# gnuplot and TexnicCenter setup

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texniccenter, gnuplot

I just downloaded and ran the gnuplot setup exe.  Now, how do I setup TeXnicCenter and gnuplot so I can use gnuplot with TikZ?

So I have been able to add `--enable-write18` but the inverted cycloid doesn't generate when I compile.

I keep receiving the error pgf warning:

> plot data file '211*Homework*8.pgf-plot.table' not found.

I have uninstalled and re-installed gnuplots.  I created the environment variable `gnuplots` located in the bin folder.  I have a file in there named `gnuplots.exe` but there is also a `pgnuplots.exe`.  If I rename `pgnu`, it will ask me to replace the `gnu` or rename it.  I have tried putting `gnuplots.exe` on the desktop and renaming pgnuplots.  I have edited command line arguments for Latex to PDf to `-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm" --enable-write18` (and I have tried `-shell-escape`).  Where the above error occurs no matter what

Does anyone actually know how to set gnuplots up in TexnicCenter with MiKTeX for Windows 7 64bit?  If so, can you walk through each piece line by line.  By that I mean, environment variable name, should `pgnuplot` in bin be renamed and replace `gnuplot`, command line argument for Latex to PDF, and whatever else is missing to rectify the plot data file not found.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz, tikz-qtree, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings,calc,fadings,decorations.pathreplacing, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
 \allsectionsfont{\sffamily\raggedright\underline} 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45]
 \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0);
 \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
 \draw[shift = {(\x,0)}, color = black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below]    {\footnotesize $\x$};
 \draw[<-] (0,-2) -- (0,0);
 \foreach \y in {0,-1}
 \draw[shift = {(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
 \draw (0pt,-10pt) node[fill = white] {\footnotesize $0$};
 \clip(0,-2) rectangle (6.2,0);
 \draw[smooth, samples = 100, domain = 0:6.28319] plot[parametric] function{t - sin((t)*180/pi), -1 + cos((t)*180/pi)};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: [Gnuplot and PDFLatex question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41669/15717)

Comment: I added \usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} but I am getting the following error: shell escape not enabled

Comment: just add `--enable-write18` option to `pdflatex` in TeXniccenter configuration see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56441/15717).

Comment: How do I do it permanently enable write 18 in latex?  I don't fully understand the instructions.  Must it be done in ever document?

Comment: see this [texniccenter screenshot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91277/15717). I don't use texniccenter. if you are free you can come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)

Comment: gnuplot or (p)gnuplots (with or without s)? Is it added to the system path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use `gnuplottex` but I have enabled the `--shell-escape` option as the following

[image]

In the second command box I have the following setting:

```
-synctex=-1 -max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm" -shell-escape
```

and that should be enough for your MWE.

Your code with the following lines commented out

```
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\raggedright\underline}
```

I get the following picture

[image]

Comment: i was about to compose the answer from the chat discussion with the OP.

Comment: I still keep receiving the error pgf warning: plot data file '211*Homework*8.pgf-plot.table' not found.  Also, that code shouldn't generate that.  It would generate a cycloid on the negative since that is the how the function is defined.

Comment: @texenthusiast I can delete this if you wish it's kind of a generic answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: no worries, your answer is simply the concise form of what we discussed at [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8549130#8549130). as discussed in chat @dustin post a new question with  your expected pdf result look like since `plot parametric` not functioning according to your expectations. give this question as reference incase required as you are able to [compile to pdf](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8549369#8549369).